# How to Tell C++ to not optimize away an expression that's thrown away?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, optimization

I want to profile a series of matrice operations to get an idea of how much time they'll take.  (I'm much less inclined to think about optimizations when I'm reminded how stupidly fast the CPU can chew through instructions, eheh)

```
for(int n = 0; n < times; ++n){
    // scrambled to miss the cache on purpose
    matrix[ rand()%matrixLen ] * matrix[ rand()%matrixLen ];
}
```

My compiler keeps optimizing this expression away.  Is there any way to get it to actually execute this code while still retaining all other optimizations?

Comment: what's your compiler?

Comment: @plinth - VS2010, I'll add the tag for that now

Comment: You could potentially mark `matrix` as `volatile` if you wanted to guarantee that the compiler couldn't just throw it away. The only problem I see with that is that it might interfere with other optimizations.

Comment: Marking it as volatile produced some 'meatier' times right away.  0.2 seconds to do 20K matrix multiplications 60 times.  So about 20% of my program's running time.  Without scrambling the order, it finishes in 0.02 seconds instead.  I have a good idea of what to do now

Comment: You should really assign the product result to some matrix, most probably the compiler is optimizing away because you don't use the result of the product for nothing (and the compiler know). Create a method that receive two matrix, return the product result, and call n times to test (it's more easy to trick inter procedural optimization).

Comment: @Clairvoire: Doing something as simple as `std::cout << matrix[0];` after the loop can prevent it from being optimized away. If you never _use_ any part of the result the compiler may toss the loop because it would have no observable effects.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - Aw, I gave that a try.  Storing the values in the loop, then outputting one at random after the loop, did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a result that is cheap, yet technically the dependent on all of them.

As an example, add them all up and extract the resulting value.

Then, either block optimizing over the return value (make a dynamic library or whatever), or output the value **outside** of your profiling code.

This can still be subject to reordering of code elements, but it mostly blocks expression elimination.  (be careful the result is difficult to generate without actually doing it -- adding is better than multiplication, for example, as once it hits `0` it could early exit by the 'as-if' rule)

Comment: This answer seems to be the most reliable way, for my purpose.  Storing the results into an array as large as the loop repeats (this mimics what the code would do in it's final form best, and lets me test multiplication without worrying about 0) and then outputting one of those resulting matrices after the loop, selected at random.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, you're going to need to use a #pragma.  How you do that is entirely compiler dependent (sorry), but there is a certain amount of commonality in the process:

```
// save your current options
#if SPEEDTEST
#pragma GCC push_options 
#pragma GSS optimize("whatever the settings are")
#endif

// ... your code

// restore options
#if SPEEDTEST
#pragma GCC pop_options
#endif
```

or in your case:

```
#if SPEEDTEST
#pragma optimize("", off)
#endif

// ... your code

#if SPEEDTEST
#pragma optimize("", on)
#endif
```

NB: `you can't use some #pragma statements within a function`

Comment: Of course, depending on the compiler and what exactly your code is doing, this may not produce a meaningful result. The run time of unoptimized code with results not used may be very different from the run time of optimized code with results used.

Answer (score 3):

You ignore the result of the computation, hence the compiler can remove it.
Just store the result:

```
<yourMatrixType> result = matrix[ rand()%matrixLen ];
for(int n = 0; n < times; ++n){
    // scrambled to miss the cache on purpose
    result *= matrix[ rand()%matrixLen ];
}
```

That should prevent the compiler from removing the computation.